# Python example f"{heading:=^30}"

Tags: python, operators, centering

I ran across this in a basic Python tutorial (https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/controlflow.html).  The example is:

```
>>> heading = "Centered string"
>>> f"{heading:=^30}"
'=======Centered string========'
```

I did some searching but all I could find was a reference to '^' as an X-OR function.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

TIA

Comment: Thanks for the link.  So, "Centered string" was centered in a field 30 characters wide - I can see that.  But how was the padding symbol '=' chosen?  Is that the default?

Comment: So, you are asking what in `=^30` could have made `=` the padding?

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out with some more reading (at least I think I did). What looked to me like an assignment (:=) symbol was a colon (:) followed by the character to be used for padding.